# Why the two following maps agree on the basis vector for $R^3$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-explanation

I cannot manage to understand the proof of the theorem below, could you elaborate why the maps agree on the basis vectors in $R^3$? For $v = (v_x,v_y,v_z)^t \in \mathbb{R}^3$ the matrix $\hat{v}$ is defined as

$$
\hat{v} = \left(
\begin{array}{lll}
0 & -v_z & v_y \\
v_z & 0 & -v_x \\
-v_y & v_x & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

[image]

> **Lema 5.4. (The hat operator).** For a vector $T\in\mathbb R^3$ and a matrix $K\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$, if $\det(K)=+1$ and $T'=KT$, then $\widehat T = K^T \widehat{T'} K$.
>
> *Proof.* Since both $K^T\widehat{(\cdot)}K$ and $\widehat{K^{-1}(\cdot)}$ are linear maps from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ one may directly verify that these two linear maps agree on the basis vectors $[1,0,0]^T$, $[0,1,0]^T$ and $[0,0,1]^T$ (using the fact that $\det(K)=1$).

This is Lemma 5.4 from An Invitation to 3-D Vision (Yi Ma et al.), [page 113](https://books.google.com/books?id=FwfSBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA113).

Comment: What is the definition of the hat operator? (Separately, it would be good of you to typeset your question using MathJaX, which will make your question searchable on this site, as well as more accessible to the visually-impaired.)

Comment: Sorry, I've added the info in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Here's another argument, not using a basis. First note that if $v \in \Reals^{3}$, then $\hat{v}$ represents the (minus) cross product in the sense that for all $w$ in $\Reals^{3}$,
$$
\hat{v} w = -v \times w.
\tag{1}
$$

If $u$, $v$, and $w$ are arbitrary vectors in $\Reals^{3}$ and $K$ is an arbitrary $3 \times 3$ real matrix, then
$$
Ku \cdot (Kv \times Kw) = (\det K) u \cdot (v \times w)
\tag{2}
$$
because the triple product $u \cdot (v \times w) = \det[u\ v\ w]$ is the (signed) volume of the parallelipiped spanned by the ordered triple $u$, $v$, $w$, and $\det K$ is the multiplicative factor for volume under multiplication by $K$.

Finally, by the definition of the dot product,
$$
Ku \cdot (Kv \times Kw) = u^{T}K^{T} (Kv \times Kw).
\tag{3}
$$

If $T' = KT$, then for all $u$ and $w$ in $\Reals^{3}$,
\begin{align*}
  u^{T}(\hat{T}w)
  &= u \cdot (\hat{T}w) && \\
  &= -u \cdot (T \times w) && (1) \\
  &= -Ku \cdot (KT \times Kw) && (2),\ \det K = +1 \\
  &= -u^{T} K^{T} (T' \times Kw) && (3),\ T' = KT \\
  &= u^{T} K^{T} \widehat{T'} K w && (1).
\end{align*}
Since $u$ and $w$ were arbitrary, the matrices in the middle are equal, i.e.,
$$
\hat{T} = K^{T}\widehat{T'}K.
$$

Comment: Good one, I hate computations.

Answer (score 2):

Take $T=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and
$$K=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\end{pmatrix}.$$Then$$\widehat{T}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}.$$On the other hand, $T'=K.T=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}\\a_{21}\\a_{31}\end{pmatrix}$. So$$\widehat{T'}=\begin{pmatrix}0&-a_{31}&a_{21}\\ a_{13}&0&-a_{11}\\-a_{12}&a_{11}&0\end{pmatrix}$$and therefore$$K^T\,\widehat{T'}\,K=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-\det K\\0&\det K&0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-1\\0&1&0\end{pmatrix}=\widehat{T}.$$The computations are similar for the other vectors of the canonical basis.

Note that in order to compute the matrix $K^T\,\widehat{T'}\,K$, you only have to compute three of its nine entries, since it is necessarily an anti-symmetric matrix.

Comment: It's literally proved by computation then.

Comment: @user8469759 Yes. My guess is that it is not hard to find a more conceptual proof, but I was unable to do it.

Comment: How did you get $$K^T\,\widehat{T'}\,K=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&-\det K\\0&\det K&0\end{pmatrix}$$?

Comment: @user8469759 Computing it.

Comment: Literally you did matrix product then?

Comment: @user8469759 Yes. Did you read the final paragraph of my answer? Computing the product meant to compute *three* entries of the final matrix, not all of them.